# Why is Scala building its own ForkJoinPool instead of using java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool#commonPool?

Tags: java, scala, threadpool

Both Java and Scala introduce their own global ForkJoinPool, Java as `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool#commonPool` and Scala as `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext#global`.
Both of these seem to be intended to be used for the same use cases, specifically running non-blocking concurrent tasks (often implicitly).
Now from what I can figure, if you pick your interop dependencies the wrong way, you will end up with two thread pools doing exactly the same thing, one for the Java world and one for the Scala world.

So unless I am missing something obvious, is there any good reason for Scala to not simply use the Java commonPool for its global ExecutionContext?

Comment: I guess one reason is that Java is not the only platform that Scala runs on. It also runs on the ECMAScript platform (Scala.js), natively (Scala-native), and there was a now-abandoned port to .NET (Scala.NET). None of those have **java**.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.

Comment: @JörgWMittag could be, but the `scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl` already depends heavily on java and actually the Scala ForkJoinPool implementation has been removed and is now an alias for the Java implementation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Our main aim is to end up with a library of definitive answers to useful questions. What you've asked is a "why did the designer make this choice" kind of question, which is primarily opinion based. All we'll get is people's guesses as to the designer's motivations, or if we're really lucky the designer's justification for what is a fairly arbitrary choice. For this reason I've voted to close as "Primarily opinion based".

Comment: @slim I disagree with you there. This question is about the reasoning behind the technical behavior, which is not usually an whimsy by the designer but based in reasoning and logical evaluation of alternatives. That makes it deducible and knowable by someone who's deeper into the subject than I am. It also means this knowledge is not limited to the designer in any way.

Answer (score 2):

To add to other answers - besides JVM version issue, usage of JVM specific implementation would bound Scala API to Java internals. Even if that wasn't the goal initially, right now Scala community would like to target more than one backend: we have Scala, Scala.js, Scala Native. If we decide to change things and couple Scala library to JVM API code will be less portable for no good reason - after all ExecutionContext on JVM still uses some Java's thread pool implementations internally, so it's not like we are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The scala library is already coupled to the Java API at this point, see [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L127). How is the current way less coupled that using the exact same API through an already existing instantiation?

Comment: This particular thing is internals - you can still write e.g. Scala.js library that uses `ExecutionContext` because it's implementation is different while API is the same: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/18a5d4d6380b279ddf0fb89844dc7c3e4dd6644d/scalalib/overrides/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.scala Sure. Java API appears here and there, but in general maintainers try to limit its usage. After all Scala only _works_ on JVM it is _not Java++_, so any tight coupling with JVM ecosystem should be a conscious decision.

Comment: (Otherwise you force e.g. Scala.js maintainers to reimplement Java interfaces in JS or Scala Native - it is already happening, but we shouldn't make things worse).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you are talking about. There is no change in interface or API anywhere around this, the question is about usage of thread pooling on the JVM. The code in question if from ExecutionContext**Impl**, not the ExecutionContext interface.